# can you use lapply/sapply on to apply an element of one list to the corresponding element of another list?

Tags: r

I've been trying to work out a problem I'm having with a couple of lists I have.

I'm playing around with creating my own cross-validation function for a homework assignment.  Right now, I'm at a point where I've generated two lists: a list of lm class elements, and a list of resamples from my original data.

I created 5 training and 5 test resamples using the modelr package's crossv_kfold() function, called cvtest

```
cvtest<-crossv_kfold(MyDataSet,5)
```

I created a list of 5 linear models using the training sets from cvtest using lapply

```
linModFunc<-function(data,form){
    lm(form,data)
    }

lmodtest<-lapply(cvtest$train,linModFunc,form=formula)
```

right now, I'm trying to calculate the RSME's of each linear model in conjunction with it's training set.

I was trying to figure out a way to manipulate lapply or sapply to get element 1 of cvtest, element 1 of lmodtest, apply the rmse function, and continue down both of the lists.

basically I'd like to get the result of this:

```
rmse(lmodtest,cvtest)
```

but something that actually works.
Is there a good way of doing this?  I think I could do it with a for loop, but but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: `Map(somefunc, cvtest, lmodtest)`?

Comment: Hmmm... that's from purrr, right?  I think I might be able to use that.  but wouldn't it change the output from a list to dataframe?  I'm not super familiar with the package.

Comment: Nope. `Map` is to `lapply` as `mapply` is to `sapply`. And all base-R. (You're thinking of the lower-case `map` ... easy to confuse.)

Comment: So for your other question, `Map` (like `lapply`) always returns a `list`, so it can operate on frames or lists or vectors just fine.

Comment: And further, `purrr::map` returns a `list`. You may also be thinking of `purrr::map_dfr` and `purrr::map_dfc`, which *"return data frames created by row-binding and column-binding respectively"* (from [`?map`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map)).

Comment: It worked perfectly!  I just had to add $train to access the correct list for the calculation.  Thank you so much!

Comment: FYI: `Map(func, list_of_data)` is identical in effect as `lapply(list_of_data, func)` (though it is just a shade slower). The biggest benefit of `Map` is that it accepts one *or more* lists to "zip" together, whereas `lapply` (and friends) only accepts one list-of-data.